# Using WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP window style with Vulkan

Tags: winapi, vulkan

Does it make sense to use `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` window style when rendering with Vulkan?

From MSDN:

> WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP The window does not render to a redirection surface. This is for windows that do not have visible content or that use mechanisms other than surfaces to provide their visual.

It would be reasonable to assume that as we create our own surface with `vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR` and swapchain with buffers with `vkCreateSwapchainKHR` we do not need any intermediate surface to render to.

When setting `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` it does work as expected on NVidia GPU (content is rendered, didn't measure a performance benefit though), however it doesn't work on Intel GPU (content is not visible, window is completely transparent).

Comment: [Windows with C++ : High-Performance Window Layering Using the Windows Composition Engine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745861.aspx) shows a sample using DirectX. You can try to port this to using Vulkan, or just use it as a reference to see where your implementation might be wrong.

Comment: Seems to work for me on AMD.